# Pandas normalize API call json

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I have tried to normalize this json API for every columns but I couldn't. I tried several response from here for this topic but I could not find it for my issue.
The problem is because there are some cases has not EMAIL

This is the json data:

```
    data =[{'ID': '11348',
          'NAME': 'Yanara',
          'LAST_NAME': 'Araneda',
          'LEAD_ID': '17772',
          'EMAIL': [{'ID': '42400',
            'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
            'VALUE': 'yanara.araneda.moraga@gmail.com',
            'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}]},
         {'ID': '11346',
          'NAME': 'Carlos ',
          'LAST_NAME': 'Gonzalez ',
          'LEAD_ID': '17782',
          'EMAIL': [{'ID': '42390',
            'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
            'VALUE': 'cmgclima@gmail.com',
            'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}]},
         {'ID': '11344',
          'NAME': 'Alcides',
          'LAST_NAME': 'Gonzalez',
          'LEAD_ID': '11006',
          'EMAIL': [{'ID': '42376',
            'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
            'VALUE': 'makogonzalez@gmail.com',
            'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}]}
         {'ID': '9752', 
          'NAME': 'Oriana', 
          'LAST_NAME': 'Mejias', 
          'LEAD_ID': None}]]
```

I have tried

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

But the output is:

```
     ID      NAME       LAST_NAME   LEAD_ID                   EMAIL
0   11348   Yanara       Araneda     17772  {'ID': '42400', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK', 'VALUE':...
1   11346   Carlos       Gonzalez    17782  {'ID': '42390', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK', 'VALUE':...
2   11344   Alcides      Gonzalez    11006  {'ID': '42376', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK', 'VALUE':...
```

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the desired output of that `json`?

Comment: The EMAIL tag in the JSON has an embedded list.  This may mean that it will have more than one list element for each ID record in future datasets.  Depending on how you want this output, you may wish to consider exporting the list contents to a separate dataframe with the ID as something you can join to.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear what your desired output is, but possibly this could help?

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(data, 'EMAIL', ['NAME','LAST_NAME','LEAD_ID'])
      ID VALUE_TYPE                            VALUE TYPE_ID     NAME  LAST_NAME LEAD_ID
0  42400       WORK  yanara.araneda.moraga@gmail.com   EMAIL   Yanara    Araneda   17772
1  42390       WORK               cmgclima@gmail.com   EMAIL  Carlos   Gonzalez    17782
2  42376       WORK           makogonzalez@gmail.com   EMAIL  Alcides   Gonzalez   11006
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have checked the data from API and there are some cases has not 'EMAIL'.  therefore I get an error. (KeyError: 'EMAIL') Some cases are like this {'ID': '9752', 'NAME': 'Oriana', 'LAST_NAME': 'Mejias', 'LEAD_ID': None}

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your `'EMAIL'` field has a nested list instead of a dictionary. If it were, `pd.json_normalize` would have been able to still flatten it as a nested json.

For this case, you can use `pd.json_normalize` with a different `record_path` and then combine the 2 together to create a single flat table.

```
data =[{'ID': '11348',
      'NAME': 'Yanara',
      'LAST_NAME': 'Araneda',
      'LEAD_ID': '17772',
      'EMAIL': [{'ID': '42400',
        'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
        'VALUE': 'yanara.araneda.moraga@gmail.com',
        'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}]},
     {'ID': '11346',
      'NAME': 'Carlos ',
      'LAST_NAME': 'Gonzalez ',
      'LEAD_ID': '17782',
      'EMAIL': [{'ID': '42390',
        'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
        'VALUE': 'cmgclima@gmail.com',
        'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}]},
     {'ID': '11344',
      'NAME': 'Alcides',
      'LAST_NAME': 'Gonzalez',
      'LEAD_ID': '11006',
      'EMAIL': [{'ID': '42376',
        'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
        'VALUE': 'makogonzalez@gmail.com',
        'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}]}]

p1 = pd.json_normalize(data).drop('EMAIL', axis=1)
p2 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='EMAIL', record_prefix='EMAIL.')

df = p1.merge(p2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df)
```

```
      ID     NAME  LAST_NAME LEAD_ID EMAIL.ID EMAIL.VALUE_TYPE  \
0  11348   Yanara    Araneda   17772    42400             WORK   
1  11346  Carlos   Gonzalez    17782    42390             WORK   
2  11344  Alcides   Gonzalez   11006    42376             WORK   

                       EMAIL.VALUE EMAIL.TYPE_ID  
0  yanara.araneda.moraga@gmail.com         EMAIL  
1               cmgclima@gmail.com         EMAIL  
2           makogonzalez@gmail.com         EMAIL
```

---

If your data didnt have a list value for `'EMAIL'`, it would be super easy to get what you need. Only `pd.json_normalize(data)` would have been sufficient. -

```
data =[{'ID': '11348',
      'NAME': 'Yanara',
      'LAST_NAME': 'Araneda',
      'LEAD_ID': '17772',
      'EMAIL': {'ID': '42400',
        'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
        'VALUE': 'yanara.araneda.moraga@gmail.com',
        'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}},
     {'ID': '11346',
      'NAME': 'Carlos ',
      'LAST_NAME': 'Gonzalez ',
      'LEAD_ID': '17782',
      'EMAIL': {'ID': '42390',
        'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
        'VALUE': 'cmgclima@gmail.com',
        'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}},
     {'ID': '11344',
      'NAME': 'Alcides',
      'LAST_NAME': 'Gonzalez',
      'LEAD_ID': '11006',
      'EMAIL': {'ID': '42376',
        'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK',
        'VALUE': 'makogonzalez@gmail.com',
        'TYPE_ID': 'EMAIL'}}]

print(pd.json_normalize(data))
```

```
      ID     NAME  LAST_NAME LEAD_ID EMAIL.ID EMAIL.VALUE_TYPE  \
0  11348   Yanara    Araneda   17772    42400             WORK   
1  11346  Carlos   Gonzalez    17782    42390             WORK   
2  11344  Alcides   Gonzalez   11006    42376             WORK   

                       EMAIL.VALUE EMAIL.TYPE_ID  
0  yanara.araneda.moraga@gmail.com         EMAIL  
1               cmgclima@gmail.com         EMAIL  
2           makogonzalez@gmail.com         EMAIL
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. when I tried to make p2 I got a error "KeyError: 'EMAIL'"

Comment: Does your data have 'EMAIL' field in every record?

Comment: I am copy pasting the same data that you have posted on top and it runs fine for me. can you test it on your sample data that you have posted above?

Comment: Can you copy my whole code block in the first part and run it as it is?

Comment: Hi, I have checked the data from API and there are some cases has not 'EMAIL'.  therefore I get an error. (KeyError: 'EMAIL') Some cases are like this {'ID': '9752', 'NAME': 'Oriana', 'LAST_NAME': 'Mejias', 'LEAD_ID': None}

Comment: oh ok. let me see what can be done in this case.